# Celery beat not resuming scheduled tasks django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have used celery & django celery beat to run a predefined scheduled task. When I first run celery worker & then celery beat worker, everything is fine, the task is added to database, and also sent to queue by celery beat worker continuously.

But when I stop beat worker and start it again, it no longer works, even though the task is defined in database.

What should I do?

This is my code for django:

```py
# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='say hello every 10 secs')


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-12-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.test',
        'schedule': 12.0,
        # 'args': ()
    },
}
```

and this is how I start celery worker & beat worker:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

```
celery -A proj beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

Would appreciate a help...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but what i have noticed that if i delete the old tasks from database then resume the beat server again it sends the task. But then again it resumes to not sending tasks

Comment: @Sajad Rezvani Have you got the solution for this issue ? i'm facing the exact issue

Comment: @LiquidDeath Not really, I couldn't fix celery, instead I implemented my own schedular based on my needs with help of threads & processes & redis.